# how to add multiple sets in python but only if items are unique

Tags: python

I need to add an undetermined number of lists (sets), but i only want to add members if they are unique

(1,2,3)
(3,4,5)
(4,7,8,9)
(5,3,9)

would need to give: (1,2,7,8)

Comment: Why are the sets tuples?

Comment: @user2473664, if one of the answers below helped, feel free to accept (tick on left) one so that other users can see a tested solution.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can flatten the tuples and then caste as a set:

```
s = [(1,2,3), (3,4,5), (4,7,8,9), (5,3,9)]
full_set = [i for b in s for i in b]
final_s = tuple(i for i in full_set if full_set.count(i) == 1)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 7, 8)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

lst = [(1,2,3), (3,4,5), (4,7,8,9), (5,3,9)]

[k for k, v in Counter(chain.from_iterable(lst)).items() if v==1]

# [1, 2, 7, 8]
```

For minimal cost, you can also return values with count 2, 3, etc.

Comment: ... why use `concat` from third-party `toolz` instead of the equivalent `itertools.chain.from_iterable`?

Comment: simple, easier to type! these are, of course, identical. `toolz` just provides a pointer here. since more than one person thinks it's an issue, i'll amend.

Comment: it also helps meet [PEP row length guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).

Comment: Yeah, but it's probably not good to just use a third-party library in an answer that doesn't mention that library, at least not without a mention that it *is* third party and what the function does. As for length guidelines, `import itertools; concat = itertools.chain.from_iterable`

Answer (score 0):

Although `Counter` is the better solution, here is another approach:

```
import functools as ft


def get_disjoints(iterables):
    """Return a list of disjoint elements."""
    def local_symdiff(a, b):
        """Return a symmetric difference of all observations."""
        a, b = set(a), set(b)
        intersections.update(a & b)
        return {x for x in a | b if x not in intersections}

    intersections = set()
    return ft.reduce(local_symdiff, iterables)


iterables = [(1,2,3), (3,4,5), (4,7,8,9), (5,3,9)]
get_disjoints(iterables)
# {1, 2, 7, 8}
```

Pairs of iterables (via `functools.reduced`) are merged and filtered of all observed intersections.

Comment: Isn't your function `func` just returning the symmetric difference of a and b? You can do the same with `a ^ b` (where a and b are sets)

Comment: Ah, I see you're storing all of the intersections. Yea I realized that sym diff wouldn't work straight up with the reduce. This is a nice work around. Cool!

Comment: It's close.  The key is sym diff must be for all observations.  If you used  `a ^ b` between reduced pairs, you will see `3` pop up in the results since it's removed at the beginning but reappears at the end.  `intersections` tracks all discarded items.  I've renamed `func`.  Thanks.

Comment: Nice. Similar to my solution but more readable. But I agree, the counter approach is preferred.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def build_list(listnums):
      nummap = {}
      for n in listnums:
          for num in n: 
               if not num in nummap:
                   nummap[num] = True
               else:
                   nummap.pop(num, None)
      return list(nummap.keys())
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a *better** solution that uses only set operations and `reduce()`:

```
all_sets = [{1,2,3}, {3,4,5}, {4,7,8,9}, {5,3,9}]
combined = reduce(
    lambda a, b: a.union(b),
    [
        s - reduce(
            lambda x, y: x.union(y), 
            [other for j, other in enumerate(all_sets) if j!=i]
        ) for i, s in enumerate(all_sets)
    ]
)
print(combined)
#set([8, 1, 2, 7])
```

Go go through each set in `all_sets` and get the distinct elements across all other sets using the set difference operator (`-`). Then we reduce the result of this operator using the set `union()` function to combine all sets.

To illustrate what's going on, here is the output of the inner list comprehension:

```
# this gets the elements in each set that are not in any of the others
inner = [
    s - reduce(
        lambda x, y: x.union(y), 
        [other for j, other in enumerate(all_sets) if j!=i]
    ) for i, s in enumerate(all_sets)
]
print(inner)
# [set([1, 2]), set([]), set([8, 7]), set([])]
```

*Better than my original solution below.

**Original Solution**

Here's a solution using list comprehensions and without counting occurrences.

```
all_sets = [{1,2,3}, {3,4,5}, {4,7,8,9}, {5,3,9}]
combined = [x for i, a in enumerate(all_sets) for x in a 
            if all(x not in b for j, b in enumerate(all_sets) if i!=j)]
print combined
#[1, 2, 7, 8]
```

Iterate though each value in each list and only add it to the combined list if it doesn't exist in any of the other lists. We use `enumerate` twice over all of the lists so we can keep track of what the "other" lists are.

Answer (score -1):

```
def findSingles(t):
    l = [n for t in tuples for n in t]
    return tuple([i for i in l if l.count(i) == 1])

tuples = ((1,2,3), (3,4,5), (4,7,8,9), (5,3,9))

print(findSingles(tuples))    
# (1, 2, 7, 8)
```